# not able to enter mouse into pop up div

Tags: javascript, html, popup

If I hover my mouse into the `<div>` area, it will move away.

I want the `<div>` to stay still when a mouse enters the div's region, then the `<div>` should disappear when I do a `mouseout` from the `<div>`, or the `<td>`.

Why can't my mouse pointer enter the `<div>` area?

```
<html>
  <div id="divPopup" onmouseout="removeDIV(this,event);" style="display:none;width:100px;height:100px;color:Navy;border:2px;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;">
    Yes its me
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S</td></tr>
    <tr><td onmouseover="loadDIV(event)" onmouseout="removeDIV(this,event);">D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td></tr>
  </table>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function loadDIV(evt) {
      var myWin = document.getElementById('divPopup');
      myWin.style.position='absolute';
      myWin.style.left = evt.x;
      myWin.style.top = evt.y;
      myWin.style.display='block';
    }

    function removeDIV(obj,evt) {
      var myWin = document.getElementById('divPopup');
      myWin.style.display='none';
      myWin.style.left = 0;
      myWin.style.top = 0;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that onmouseout event fires when you try to enter opened div.
First i suppose you need to timeout removing of div.
And second you need to place a onmouseover event on opened div where you will pause removing of div until mouse will move from the div.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the mouse over to your div as well, e.g:

```
<div id="divPopup" onmouseover="loadDIV(event)" onmouseout="removeDIV(this,event);" style="display:none;width:100px;height:100px;color:Navy;border:2px;border-color:Red;border-style:solid;">
```